# How to switch between distributed and local development versions of a package?

Tags: use-package, package-development

I use the stable version of a package (0.7.0 of `gptel`) which is distributed on melpa-stable. I installed it via `package.el` and I configure it via a `use-package`. I want to be able to switch easily between this version and a local development version of this package, which is based on a git worktree on my machine. How do I do this?

I thought it would be as easy as adding the path to the development version in my load path, either in the use-package form, or else by manually `require`ing it before package initialization. However, this doesn't work, since the package needs to be installed by `package-install-file` to work properly, and installation writes outputs into the `elpa/` directory, clobbering the stable installation.

So is there some other way to do this, ideally using just built-in facilities like `package.el` and `use-package`?

Here is what I am doing now to but it seems like a hack.

To update the development version:

1. I git pull the latest version of the package into my local dev directory
2. I modify its code so "Version" is set to "999.git", which I expect will always translate to a higher version number than any stable released using the usual major minor point versioning scheme.
3. I evaluate the expression `(package-install-file (expand-file-name "/path/to/local_dev_dir"))`, which installs the development version into `elpa/`.

To switch between to the stable version:

In `init.el`, in my `use-package` declaration for gptel, I add a keyword value pair which points explicitly to the stable version: `:load-path "/path/to/elpa/stable/version/"`